# [ant]warning.js:34 Warning: Duplicate field names will result in both fields getting edited together. Field names must be unique

Tags: javascript

[image]

When I use `this.props.form.setFieldsValue` to set ant-design form values, I got this warning, is there someone have seen this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Give unique name to each field

```
    <Form.Item label="Username">
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(<Input />)}
     </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item label="Password">
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your password!' }],
          })(<Input />)}
     </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item label="gender">
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your gender!' }],
          })(<Input />)}
     </Form.Item>
```

I assume you are providing same name to all the fields in your form like above sample code. Make unique name to each field like this

```
    <Form.Item label="Username">
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(<Input />)}
     </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item label="Password">
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your password!' }],
          })(<Input />)}
     </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item label="gender">
          {getFieldDecorator('gender', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your gender!' }],
          })(<Input />)}
     </Form.Item>
```

If this doesn't help then provide your code sample, to get more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

That seems a bug with antd.

Pls update your antd dependency.

[Learn more on github](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/17408)